# balancing on other people

Tags: exercise, yoga, balance

So the other day I saw two people sorta balancing on one another. Person A was on their back with their feet and hands in the air holding up person B who was sorta moving around on person A's hands / feet.

Kinda a vague description but it looked kinda neat. Anyone have any ideas as to what that's called? Seemed kinda like a yoga thing idk.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably acro-yoga/acrobatic yoga. Or just partner yoga. Or gymnastics. Hope that helps because this is definitely off-topic. :D

Comment: "Identify this" typed questions wont help any further visitors, these questions are not a good fit for SE sites.